Как проверить в верхнем регистре или нет латинская буква менее чем за 12 символов?
Необходимо написать функцию f на javascript, которая определяет является ли латинская буква в верхнем регистре или нет. Функция должна вернуть true, если это одна из букв A-Z или вернуть false, если это буква a-z. Код должен быть не длиннее 12 (двенадцати) символов. Ответ долженбыть true или false
Мое решение немного больше 12 символов:
f=s=>s<='Z'&&s>='A'
как написать такую же функцию меньше 12 символов?

Если ввод только такой, то достаточно проверить, что s < 'a'

/[A-Z]/.test(s) не 12 конечно... Но короче ТСа. :)

Кстати я уже и сам придумал решение f=s=>s<='Z'

f=s=>s<'['

Дело в том, что a-z идут позже A-Z. И вторую проверку можно не делать.
